# Java - different behaviours between if-else and ternary operator

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-operator

Recently I discovered a strange behaviour difference between if-else and the ternary operator.

I am going to illustrate the difference using unit test code below.

```java
public class SomeTest {

    @Test
    void testWithTernary_resultIsLong() {
        final SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        assertTrue(someClass.getNumberWithTernary() instanceof Long);
        assertFalse(someClass.getNumberWithTernary() instanceof Integer);
    }

    @Test
    void testWithIfElse_resultIsInteger() {
        final SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        assertTrue(someClass.getNumberWithIfElse() instanceof Integer);
        assertFalse(someClass.getNumberWithIfElse() instanceof Long);
    }

    private static class SomeClass {

        public Object getNumberWithTernary() {
            final long l = this.getLong();
            return (l >= Integer.MIN_VALUE && l <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? Math.toIntExact(l) : l;
        }

        private long getLong() {
            return 10L;
        }

        public Object getNumberWithIfElse() {
            final long l = this.getLong();
            if (l >= Integer.MIN_VALUE && l <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                return Math.toIntExact(l);
            } else {
                return l;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both the tests above succeed.

The class declared above is overly simplified from the code I encountered at work.

The main method is returning an `Object`, and the method needs to return an integer whenever possible (ie. within Integer range) for easier consumption in upstream.

I initially used the ternary operation approach and never thought it would work unexpectedly, until doing smoke test.

Can anyone explain why the behaviour of if-else and ternary operator differ in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze your ternary expression `(...) ? Math.toIntExact(l) : l`

Condition does not matter. Second operand ("then" part) is of type `int`. Third operator ("else" part) is of type `long`.

You can read Java Language Specification **15.25. Conditional Operator ? :** for precise rules. But basically all numeric operands are casted to the "widest" type, because expression result must have a single type, you can't return "either `long` or `int`", Java type system is not powerful enough (some languages actually can do that).

So basically compiler rewrites that expression to the following expression:

```
(...) ? ((long) Math.toIntExact(l)) : l
```

And to convert `long` to `Object`, compiler inserts autoboxing call:

```
Long.valueOf((...) ? ((long) Math.toIntExact(l)) : l)
```

So that's a rough explanation of why you're seeing this behaviour.

Ordinary `if` statement can't return value, so it just returns whatever you specified in `return` statement without further numeric promotions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It is very clear to me now why the difference.